# Why is my name attached to my email address when I send an email?

Tags: gmail

I'd like to send emails that don't have my name attached to sender's email address.  How do I strip my name from the sender address?

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because that's the generally accepted standard and that's the way Gmail does it. It makes sense, because people can choose anything for an email address and it doesn't have to do anything with their name. How else will you know "willcodeforfood@example.com" is John Smith?

As for stripping it from your outgoing mail, I'm afraid that's not possible with Gmail all by itself. Gmail adds your profile name automatically. You'll need to use a third-party email client for that.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could consider replacing your profile name with a alphabet or any other set of letters. I checked if the email address itself can be used as name but the @ character isn't allowed.

Note that you can only change your name 3 times within a 90-day period.